# reviewdog: this is not PullRequest build

Tags: git, github, circleci

## Overview

I have a trouble with reviewdog.
I would like to be able run reviewdog on CircleCI, and when I did `git push`, it will check the documentation for text errors, and reviewdog will send out a pull-request if there is an error.

## .config.yml

```
# ref: https://github.com/azu/textlint-reviewdog-example
version: 2.1

jobs:
  proofreading_job:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:lts
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: "Install textlint"
          command: npm install --save-dev textlint textlint-rule-common-misspellings
      - run:    
          name: "Install dependent module"
          command: npm install
      - run:
          name: "Install reviewdog"
          command: |
            curl -sfL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reviewdog/reviewdog/master/install.sh| sh -s
      - run: # (d1)
          name: "Execute textlint for README.md"
          command: npx textlint --rule common-misspellings README.md >> .textlint.log
      - run: # (d2)
          name: "Execute reviewdog"
          when: on_fail
          command: |
            cat .textlint.log | ./bin/reviewdog -f=checkstyle -name="textlint" -reporter="github-pr-review"

workflows:
  version: 2
  proofreading:
    jobs:
      - proofreading_job
```

## README.MD

```
# textlint-reviewdog-sample
This isnt miss.
```

I set them and I did `git push`.
Job, `Execute reviewdog` said,

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
cat .textlint.log | ./bin/reviewdog -f=checkstyle -name="textlint" -reporter="github-pr-review"
reviewdog: this is not PullRequest build.
CircleCI received exit code 0
```

reviewdog could not send out a pull-request.

In advance, I set Environment Variables, REVIEWDOG_GITHUB_API_TOKEN.
[REVIEWDOG_GITHUB_API_TOKEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEf73.png)
And I turn on the checkbox, **Only build pull requests**
[Only build pull requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2Lef.png)

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue.

## Solution

I made a mistake below the code.

`npx textlint --rule common-misspellings README.md >> .textlint.log`

I need to add  `-f checkstyle`.

I fix and issue PR on another branch.

https://github.com/Yuhta28/textlint-reviewdog-sample/pull/6

reviewdog made a comment.